# Homogeneous function differentiation calculus 3

Tags: calculus

Not sure how to take the arbitrary differentiation of this:
[Here's the photo of the problem from a practice final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8Lhm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let $u=tx$ and $v=ty$ then, $f(tx,ty)=f(u,v)$. And $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}$ by the chain rule. Then set $t=1$ so that $x=u$ and hence $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$.

Answer (score 0):

You have not telled, that  we have

$$f(tx,ty)=t^2f(x,y) !!$$

Let $g(t)=f(tx,ty)$ . Differentiation with respect to $t$ gives (chain rule !):

(1)  $g'(t)=xf(tx,ty)+yf_y(tx,ty)$.

From $g(t)=t^rf(x,y)$ we get

(2) $g'(t)=2tf(x,y)$

For $t=1$:

$$2f(x,y)=g'(1)=xf_x(x,y)+yf_y(x,y)$$